# Why is my this.setState not working in a function?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        checked: false,
    };
  }

  // this.setState is not working here.
  changeLike = () => { this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked}) }

  _renderItem = ( item ) => {

      return(
    <View style={styles.news_item}>
      <View style={styles.unlikeIcon}>
        { this.state.checked === false && 
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.changeLike}>
            <Image 
              style={{tintColor: 'red', width: 25, height: 25}}
              source={require('../../assets/imgs/unlike.png')}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        }
        { this.state.checked === true && 
           <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.changeLike}>
             <Image 
               style={{tintColor: 'red', width: 25, height: 25}}
               source={require('../../assets/imgs/likepic.png')}
             />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            }
        </View>    
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
           return(
        <View>
          <FlatList 
            data={this.state.data}
            keyExtractor={ (index) => index.toString() }
            renderItem={ ({item}) => this._renderItem(item) }
          />
        </View>
       );
  } 
}
```

My `this.setState` is not working in the `_renderItem` function which called from the Flatlist. Also, I haven't posted the rest of the code in _renderItem because it isn't necessary here.

I'm using this code as a **Checkbox** alternative. Please help, I don't know what's wrong here. I've also tried using a callback function with `setState`

Comment: probably because `this` points to the object inside of which the code is, and the `this.setState` is called inside `=> { }` (new object). Try using `Home.this`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko `this` where?

Comment: did not finish comment, and misclicked enter Now it's finished

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko so can you please this and tell me where do I need to correct my code?

Comment: wherever you need to use `this.setState` try using `Home.this.setState`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I tried. Didn't work for me.

Comment: what is says/shows in this case?

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Home.this.setState')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually working and the state will correctly be updated, but the FlatList isn't since it only rerenders when `this.state.data` changes. If you want to update the FlatList with other state or props, you need to make use of the `extraData` prop.

```
<FlatList 
  data={this.state.data}
  keyExtractor={ (index) => index.toString() }
  renderItem={ ({item}) => this._renderItem(item) }
  extraData={this.state.checked} // this is the magic
/>
```

Comment: I've a question. What if I had to pass another parameter to extraData. What if I had to also pass `this.state.data` ?

Comment: You can add an array to extraData as well, so `extraData=[this.state.someData, this.state.otherData]` is also valid

Comment: Yes indeed, my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Provide unique keys to `TouchableOpacity` components

Refer to this guide https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys

Comment: `<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.changeLike} key="first_TouchableOpacity ">`

Comment: How do I use it?

Comment: React identifies components with keys. At render he provides them himself, but outside you need to specify them yourself. Like in your example. I updated the answer with guide link, please refer to it for better explanation.

Comment: Thank you. Checkout @dentemm answer, it worked for me.